# Find the path of kermit directory to put after shebang (#!) in script

Tags: scripting, shebang, kermit

I used the following script to connect to my serial device using `kermit`:

```
#!/usr/bin/kermit
set port /dev/ttyUSB8
set speed 115200
set carrier-watch off
set flow-control none
set prefixing all
OUTPUT ifconfig\13
```

But it throws the following error:

```
bash: ./test.script: /usr/bin/kermit^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I suspect that the path I give after the shebang could be the issue. How do I find the right path to get my script working?

Comment: Is that a `^M` in the error message? Does the file have DOS newlines maybe?

Comment: That's exactly what caused the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the shebang you have the command to be executed. The script name will be the second argument. So in case of bash you have `#!/bin/bash` which is equivalent to call `bash ./script`.  In your case, the command is equivalent to:

`sudo /usr/bin/kermit ./test.script`

You should check if kermit is installed and if it is in `/usr/bin` e.g. using the command `which kermit`.

EDIT.

Ah. now I found the error.
You have a ^M (CR) on the first line. Go to the first line of script, remove the end of line and redo it. This in Unix/Linux.  DOS/Windows will add the ^M, which is not well interpreted.

Comment: `kermit` is installed and is there in `/usr/bin`. The following is the output of which:
user4@user4-pc-4:~/Scripts$ which kermit
/usr/bin/kermit

Comment: Edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

The `^M` is a carriage-return which suggests that your script might have been  composed on a Windows machine.

To remove the carriage returns, leaving bare newlines, do:

```
perl -pi.old -e 's{\r}{}' file
```

This performs an inplace update, first backing up the original file as ".old".